# How to get missing references from Exception

Tags: c#, dll, pdftron

I've just deployed my app on a new server.

As I started it I got this Exception.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PDFNet.dll'
or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

I after hours of debugging and re-adding references I found out about [dependency walker.](http://dependencywalker.com/)

It turned out the new server was missing **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package**

Now my question is:

**Is there any way to get that info from the exception or elsewhere at runtime so I can show a helpful messagebox and log the error correctly ?**

Comment: No, the OS loader is not chatty enough to provide this info.  But can be configured to be by hand, google "windows enable loader snaps".  Depends.exe has not been maintained for a very long time and cannot diagnose loader features added in the past decade, SysInternals' Process Monitor is a better bet.  Advice you'd find in about any SO question about the runtime error btw.

Comment: Fusion Logging would record this for you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Comment: You could try switching on [Fusion logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer).  That would show .Net assembly  dependency issues, not sure if it would show the problem with the C++ Distributable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments to the answer stated, by default this information is not available.

However, the issue is one of deployment.

> I've just deployed my app on a new server.

Since you are deploying to a server, then you know if it is 64bit or 32bit, and you can install the dependency one time (or make it part of your deployment dependencies).

Or you can put the two C++ runtime DLL's into what ever the working directory is of the process that is using PDFNet, if that is obvious, and stable, location.

So I would not recommend bothering with a runtime check, which is non-trivial, and instead just make sure this dependency is clear in however you create new servers. Once there, and assuming no one deletes the DLL's, then it will always work fine.

> I after hours of debugging and re-adding references

Sorry about any frustration with this. For future readers, this information is available here.
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/windows/guides/deployment#net